# HTTP error 409 (Conflict) : Response for a Post method in a WebAPI

Tags: angular, http, http-post

so i m  building an angular 4 app and i m using a web API with  entity  frameworkin order to store my data .

i m using a service in angular that implements a Post method and this is my Post method in myservice.ts

```js
PostShopProds(pers:ShopProds){

 let body = JSON.stringify(pers); 
 let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ method:RequestMethod.Post,headers: headers });
        headers.append('Cache-Control','no-cache');
        return this._http.post("http://localhost:3980/api/shopcarts", body, options).map(res=>res.json()); 
     
      }
```

and this how i called the method post in angular :

```js
let element =new ShopProds(id,this.general.login,nombre);
this.shoprodS.PostShopProds(element).subscribe(x=>this.Shopcarts=x);
```

and those are the errors that appears when i build the app:

[the errors image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFRZb.jpg)

Comment: is the server running at `http://localhost:3980/api/shopcarts` implemented by you? If not, then check with the server implementation. The server responds with 409 error code most likely because of a similar resource is already created there.